# Installing phpmyadmin in Filezilla

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, filezilla

I'm making my first steps learning how to develop a Wordpress theme. I installed Wordpress in local, I designed a theme and now I'm learning how to export it to a live site.

I have the server address, the user and the password of my client. I downloaded filezilla, I logged in and I decided to make a subdirectory in his actual site to install the wordpress site. So it woud be something like this [www.clientsite.com/wordpressnewsite](http://www.clientsite.com/wordpressnewsite).

The thing is that I suppose that I have to install phpMyAdmin in this subdirectory so like this I can import my database.

I downloaded phpMyAdmin, I saved all the files in my subdirectory and I created a config directory inside with all the permissions.

Now I tried to go to http://www.clientsite.com/wordpressnewsite/phpmyadmin/setup/ to continue the installation but it shows a white page without a message or something.

Do you have some recommendation?

Comment: Check with your hosting they might already have phpmyadmin installed.

Comment: Probably ther is an error, which not displayed, because of server-settings. [error_reporting ()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php), [display_errors()](http://php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

Comment: But there were'nt a phpmyadmin folder installed when I accessed to the server in filezilla. So I supose that my hosting doesn't have phpmyadmin installed

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. Its likely if you use cpanel you already have phpmyadmin. its not advisable to leave it in a accessible web directory, or hackers gonna get you.
2. If you have that phpmyadmin folder under your wordpress install its likely that it may not work as the htaccess file for wordpress is trying to send everything through wordpress.

In the phpmyadmin folder you could enter the following in the htaccess file.

RewriteEngine Off.